# How to get transaction link into etherumscan to my website using etherumscan API

Tags: metamask, javascript, etherscan, ethers.js

please help me with my problem :
I am creating a website with blockchain. Now I need to get my transaction results into etherscan.io to my website with a link for this transaction and all these by using etherscan API.
EXAMPLE: I need to have same this link on my website after any transaction is done.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x6750e4e507916b37716077bc24737dce133f53718e2d6eb435d2d999e7278b60

thanks all ^^

Answer (score 1):

see if the transaction hash is generated it means it is successful transaction and in order to get transaction hash you can use
" let txConfirm = await provider.getTransaction(FUNCTION_NAME.hash) "
and just concat the result after generating transaction hash i.e in my case txConfirm to the "https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/".concat(txConfirm)

Comment: please get me more explanation about FUNCTION_NAME.hash ?

Comment: When you send a transaction in you app, you get a "transaction receipt". This transaction receipt is an object that contains a `transactionHash`. In order to generate a link to the Etherscan explorer, you just need to concatenate the base url "https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/" with your transaction hash.